# Ethrogh "Lineage"

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I've been reading a lot about ethruggim lately, and there is talk of Assad strands, and Morning Star Temoni lineage. Is the "Morning Star Temoni" lineage different than all the normal Yemenite Ethruggim available for purchase?